# GridView in LoginView giving wrong row count

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView within a LoginView that I am getting an Index Out Of Range error with.  When I display the # of rows in the GridView it always shows 0 which is causing this error.

> Is there something specific that I need to be doing to get a GridView
>   to properly work within a LoginView?

Below is the code that is being run when I click on a button in the GridView and the error only comes up on the GridView `row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];` line.  If I use only `e.RowIndex` I do not get the error and it will actually return the proper number.  If I do gv.DataKeys.Count it will return the correct count.  If I do `gv.Rows.Count` it will always be 0.  I think it has something to do with a PostBack because if I do a row count in my `page_load` then it returns the correct count.  Please let me know if there is anything else that you need for me to post?

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView gv = ReviewLoginView.FindControl("gvReview") as GridView;
        GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        string Id = (row.FindControl("lblID") as Label).Text;

        string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObservationCardCS"];
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("cardReview"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        GridView gv = ReviewLoginView.FindControl("gvReview") as GridView;

        int index = e.RowIndex;

        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblError.Text = ex.Message + " " + index.ToString() + " " + gv.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

Below is the LoginView from the aspx page.

```
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ID="ReviewLoginView">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
        <%--<AnonymousTemplate>--%>
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvReview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EnableViewState="true"
                    EmptyDataText="No records have been added." AllowSorting="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#e0e0e0" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#d0d0d0" ViewStateMode="Disabled"
                    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ShowHeader="false" Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' CssClass="cmsID"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmittedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("submittedBy") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("location") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmittedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("submittedDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="What Was Observed?">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWhatWasObserved" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("whatWasObserved") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="What Action Was Taken?">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWhatActionWasTaken" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("whatActionWasTaken") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="What Agreement Was Reached?">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWhatAgreementWasReached" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("whatAgreementWasReached") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="editbutton" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Review" ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Review" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            </LoggedInTemplate> 
        <%--</AnonymousTemplate>--%>
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
            You must login to view submitted Observation Cards.
        </AnonymousTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
```

Below is the BindGrid()

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObservationCardCS"]);
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("cardSelectNew2", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = comm;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Begin", "1/1/1950");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", "12/31/2049");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reviewed", "0");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", "CH.id");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AscDesc", "Asc");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRange", "Last 30 Days");

            comm.Connection = conn;
            sda.SelectCommand = comm;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            GridView gv = ReviewLoginView.FindControl("gvReview") as GridView;

            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Below is my page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        lblError.Text = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: fyi inside your using you do not need to call the close method `con.Close()` also what is the stored procedure doing is this a Select Query Update Query ..? if it's a Select Query you need to change the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery to utilize either a DataAdapeter of the Datatable.Fill method..

Comment: The Stored Proc is simply marking record as "reviewed" by checking a bit column.  I have the Datatable.Fill method in my BindData() code.

Comment: please show your markup

Comment: ok, that's fine then.. have you tried debugging the code.. perhaps you should be checking the record count of the Datatable instead. where are you re-assigning the datasource to the datatable after the update?

Comment: Just added more of the code.  Please let me know if this still isn't enough and what else you may need to see.  I have been trying to debug the code and did check the record count in the DB.  I actually get a result set in the web page and can click on the button that executes the OnRowDeleting but it is at that point that I get the Index Out Of Range error from the Row Count being 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track! But without seeing the whole class and markup we can only speculate.

Check that you are not clearing or rebuilding the data on the page load event handler, if the Grid and datasource is defined in the markup then it should cache or requery the data between page postbacks, check that you have set EnableRowCache on the GridView so that you dont have to re-query for the data during postbacks.

It looks like you are using the #OldSchool BindGrid() data load pattern, perhaps the simplest solution may be to ensure that the data is loaded first by calling BindGrid before you try to access the rows:

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
    try
    {
... delete logic
        this.BindGrid(); // re-load after the change
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
...
    }
}
```

Without enabling the row cache though you have to ensure that the same data is loaded into the grid in the same order or delete logic like this based on row index (instead of the primary key of the row) could result in you deleting the wrong data row.

Comment: Every time that I try to post the code in it's entirety I get a formatting error.  Is there something specific that I can post that would help?  I did add code in my page_load to make sure BindGrid() only executes when needed.  I added the this.BindGrid() before my try/catch in the OnRowDeleting method and I no longer the error but now nothing happens.  From what I see I do not see anywhere that I am rebuilding the data in between page_load and OnRowDeleting.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the ViewStateMode="Disabled" on the grid... or explicitly set it to enabled.

Comment: Tried removing and explicitly setting to enabled.  Still did not work properly.  This one has me perplexed!

Comment: This actually was it!  I was changing another ViewState setting on accident.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you change the way you handle delete, by using commands on the row you can pass in the key value so you don't need to lookup the row that was clicked at all. Otherwise can you declare the data source in the markup, instead of doing it in the code behind.